# Access Firestore ID generator on the front end

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set my document ids on the front end, at the same time I `set` the doc, so I was wondering if there is a way to generate Firestore IDs, which could look like this:

```
const theID = firebase.firestore().generateID() // something like this

firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(theID).set({
    id: theID,
    ...otherData
})
```

I could use `uuid` or some other id generator package, but I'm looking for a Firestore id generator. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49595334/9957187) points to some [newId method](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/73a586c92afe3f39a844b2be86086fddb6877bb7/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L36), but I can't find it in the JS SDK... (https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT**: Chris Fischer's answer is more up to date, and using `crypto` to generate random bytes is probably more secure (although you might have trouble trying to use `crypto` in non node environments, like React Native for example).

**Original Answer:**

After asking in the RN Firebase discord chat, I was pointed to [this util function](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/62715f894e559e75cf4761581938f04c16b48e74/src/utils/index.js#L357) deep in the react-native-firebase lib. It's essentially the same function as that the SO answer I mentioned in my question refers too (see the code in firebase-js-sdk [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/7043422243ff0aa8f298a04cbc8f0450856c0908/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L25)).

Depending on which wrapper you use around Firebase, the ID generation util is not necessarily exported/accessible. So I just copied it in my project as a util function:

```
export const firestoreAutoId = (): string => {
  const CHARS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

  let autoId = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    autoId += CHARS.charAt(
      Math.floor(Math.random() * CHARS.length)
    )
  }
  return autoId
}
```

Sorry, for the late reply :/ Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

```
import {randomBytes} from 'crypto';

export function autoId(): string {
  const chars =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let autoId = '';
  while (autoId.length < 20) {
    const bytes = randomBytes(40);
    bytes.forEach(b => {
      // Length of `chars` is 62. We only take bytes between 0 and 62*4-1
      // (both inclusive). The value is then evenly mapped to indices of `char`
      // via a modulo operation.
      const maxValue = 62 * 4 - 1;
      if (autoId.length < 20 && b <= maxValue) {
        autoId += chars.charAt(b % 62);
      }
    });
  }
  return autoId;
}
```

Taken from the Firestore Node.js SDK: 
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/4f4574afaa8cf817d06b5965492791c2eff01ed5/dev/src/util.ts#L52

Comment: I was unable to get this working with typescript since the crypto library is unavailable. I tried to get it working with crypto-js but gave up. Would be interested if someone finds a solution

Comment: See my just posted solution @jcroll

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be:

1. Install @google-cloud/firestore
   `npm install @google-cloud/firestore`
2. And then import and use `autoId` when needed:

```
import {autoId} from "@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/util";
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to add a new document with a unique id?

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document .

> sometimes there isn't a meaningful ID for the document, and it's more convenient to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling add()
>
> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call doc()
>
> Behind the scenes, .add(...) and .doc().set(...) are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient.

### add()

> ```
>     // Add a new document with a generated id.
>     db.collection("cities").add({
>         name: "Tokyo",
>         country: "Japan"
>     })
>     .then(function(docRef) {
>         console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
>     })
>     .catch(function(error) {
>         console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
>     });test.firestore.js
> ```

#### doc()

> ```
>     // Add a new document with a generated id.
>     var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();
>     // later...
>     newCityRef.set(data);
> ```

Comment: I know I can get Firestore to auto generate ids for me by using `add()`. What i'm wondering is if I can generate the id **before** creating the document, via some sort of method call on the front end. Like this, I don't need to make an extra query if I wanna store the id inside the document data.

Comment: Why do you want to store the id inside the document data? Why don't you use  DocumentReference.id? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id .

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find how to get access to AutoId.newId() from the firestore library.  But, there's actually a more secure way to get an ID from the window.crypto library in the browser (code sample in TypeScript - just remove types for JS).

```
// Use crypto api to generate random string of given length (in bytes)
// Note that characters are hex bytes - so string is twice as long as
// requested length - but has 8 * bytes bits of entropy.
function generateId(bytes: number): string {
    let result = "";
    // Can't use map as it returns another Uint8Array instead of array
    // of strings.
    for (let byte of crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(bytes))) {
        result += byte.toString(16);
    }
    return result;
}
```