# Firebase Firestore - Limit the number of product-documents users can create

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an Angular web-app with Firebase as the serverless backend technology. The current purpose of the web-app is to let registered users create documents for offered products. While business users can create unlimited product-docs, free users should only be able to create one product-doc.

**Collections:**

- users - `{id: string, isBusiness: boolean, name: string, email: string, productIds: string[]}`
- products - `{id: string, title: string, description: string, userId: string}`

Whenever a user creates a new product-doc with

```js
  public createProduct(id: string, product: Product) {
    return this.afStore.collection('products').doc(id).set(product, { merge: true });
  }
```

I run a cloud function with the trigger `onCreate` to add the `id` of the created product-doc to the `productIds` field of the according user-doc. This allows me to check frontend-side `if(!user.isBusiness && productIds.length > 1)` to limit the creation of multiple product-docs for free user accounts.

However, I recently did a pen-test and the testers accidentality found out that if you open the website on multiple browser tabs and simultaneously run the `createProduct()` function on each tab at the same time, all of them will execute allowing a non business user to have several product-docs.

Has anybody dealt with a similar situation? I don´t know if there is a way to avoid this with Firestore Security Rules, or if there is something to wait until active transactions are finished.

Comment: Did you meant `if(!user.isBusiness && productIds.length > 1)`?

Comment: You must check out Custom Claims and Security rules. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: @SivuyileTGMagutywa I already have a property `isBusiness` in the Firestore database. Isn´t it redundant to also maintain the custom claim in Firebase Authentication?

Comment: @BarT Yes, thanks, it was a typo in stackoverflow, but I have it correct in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation suffers from a race condition: A 'non-business' user may create an arbitrary number of products until the first productId is written to the user doc.

In my eyes, the most straightforward way to solve this, is to pre-populate the non-business users with a productId, and restrict their ability to assign new ones.

- When the non-business user is created, you create/reserve a unique productId for them, which they may or may not use. Store it in the user document.
- When a non-business user creates a product, they can only write data to that one productId. While not needed to fix the described use case, depending on your security requirements you may want to enforce this through a security rule or a cloud function.
- No matter how many concurrent tabs try to create products, they will always write to the same productId.

```js
public createProduct(id: string, product: Product, user: User) {
    if (user.isBusiness) {
      return this.afStore.collection('products').doc(id).set(product, { merge: true });
    } else {
      return this.afStore.collection('products').doc(user.reservedProductId).set(product, { merge: true });
    }    
}
```

**Caveat**: As with **any** frontend code, this will not prevent malicious actors from manipulating it to their liking. If this behaviour is a security concern, you will want to restrict write access to the products collection by non-business users. Consider implementing an appropriate security rule / cloud function. You can only trust the backend.

Comment: This approach seems to make a lot of sense and also might even work with the limited possibilities of Firestore´s security rules. Something like ``exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/products/$(request.resource.data.reservedProductId));`` to see if the non-business user has already created his one productDoc.
Should I be concerned that if I reserve too many Firestore Ids with `createId()` of AngularFire that I run into duplicate Ids?

Comment: Glad I could help. My understanding is that `createId()` guarantees a unique id (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51403280/4043295), so I believe you don't have to worry about collisions here :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `productCounter` node in users. Then merge your rules with the following:

```js
    {
      "rules": {
        "cascade_your_nodes": {
          "products": {
            "$productId" : {
              .".write": "root.child('YOUR_PATHS').child('users').child(auth.uid).child('productCounter').val() < 1 || data.exists() || root.child('YOUR_PATHS').child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isBusiness').val()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Reasoning:**
If it doesn't clash with any existing rules, Any writes to any `productId` will only be allowed if:

1. Requesting `uid` node has `productCounter` less than 1

   ```
   root.child('YOUR_PATHS').child('users').child(auth.uid).child('productCounter').val() < 1
   ```
2. If any data existed in that node (to allow updates to the nodes)

   ```
   data.exists()
   ```
3. If requesting `uid` node has `isBusiness` to `true`

   ```
   root.child('YOUR_PATHS').child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isBusiness').val()
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but this syntax seems to be for the Realtime Database and not Firestore.